# TezBox doesn't allow me to send Tezos tokens after Babylon / can't migrate to Galleon either

Tags: tezbox

I'm sorry I had a problem,
I can't send my Tezos tokens anywhere; neither Tz1 or KT1 accounts.
I restore my web Chrome TezBox but it did not work. I tried to upgrade to the newest Babylon supported 6.1 version of TezBox, but no matter how many times I do it, it still shows that the version is v5.0.2 connected to PsCARTHA.
I tried to install Galleon to migrate it, installed but when importing (using seeds or private key) it, in the end, I get just an all grey window inside Galleon... it is stuck there.
Has anyone resolved this? I'm desperate for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Tezbox is officially dead. Please move to an alternative wallet which is actively maintained like Galleon, Kukai or Ledger Live to name a few